# Changed View Join With Actual Table Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having a SQL Query which is having join with the View.

View Consist of two table simple join.

So i replaced the view with join to the base table join.

Earlier Query Was

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sts.st_id,md.MarketId,fc.ct_desc MarketName         
INTO #tempReviewMarketIds                    
FROM #MarketIds md        
JOIN [dbo].[table1] fc  ON md.MarketId = fc.ct_id         
JOIN [dbo].[viewname] sts ON fc.ct_pkey = sts.ct_pkey
```

Structure Of View:

```
create view viewname as  
select s.st_id, c.ct_pkey from   
  table1 c   
  join table2 a on c.ct_pkey = a.ae_ctpkey  
  join table3 s on a.ae_pkey = s.st_aepkey;
```

Final Query :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT s.st_id,md.MarketId,fc.ct_desc MarketName  
FROM #MarketIds md        
JOIN [dbo].[table1] fc     ON md.marketid = fc.ct_id 
JOIN table2 a     ON fc.ct_pkey = a.ae_ctpkey 
JOIN table3 s   ON a.ae_pkey = s.st_aepkey;
```

Earlier That query cost was 80% but now the query cost increased to 86%.

I am putting values in the temp table.Mainly Insert option increases in %age.

I have learned that join with view always slows the query and more I/O,O/P.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: join with view won't slow down the query,view is just to encapsulate definition(unless you use indexed views).share execution plan,schema and counts of table involved